# Reflect specific framework version?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

Using Mono.Cecil

```
if (MethodDefinition.ReturnType == AssemblyDefinition.MainModule.Import(typeof(string)))
```

Is failing because the assembly I reading is .net 2 but my program is .net 4. So it is trying to compare string v2 and string v4 so it will never be equal. How can I get the string from v2 without building my program with .net 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712265/injecting-generatedcodeattribute-with-mono-cecil)

In short, you should be able to get the `string` type with this :

```
AssemblyDefinition.MainModule.TypeSystem.String
```